# Resta de 2 sumas en sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo este query

```
    SELECT  
        t.SI_Articulo,  
        m.SI_Descripcion,  
        t.SI_UM,
        CASE WHEN c.SI_OV IS NOT NULL THEN '*' ELSE NULL END SI_OV,
        (COUNT(DISTINCT t.SI_Ubicacion)) SI_Ubicacion,
        (SUM(DISTINCT t.SI_Existencia)) SI_Existencia,
        (SUM(DISTINCT c.SI_Cantidad)) SI_Cantidad,
        (SUM(DISTINCT c.SI_Cantidad) - SUM(DISTINCT t.SI_Existencia)) SI_DIF 
FROM SI_Inventario_Teorico_QAD t 
INNER JOIN SI_Maestro_Ref_QAD m 
    ON m.SI_Num_Articulo = t.SI_Articulo 
INNER JOIN SI_Conteo c 
    ON c.SI_Num_Articulo = t.SI_Articulo
GROUP BY t.SI_Articulo,  
         m.SI_Descripcion,
         t.SI_UM,  
         c.SI_OV
```

[img de muestra](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Dy0X.png)

El problema que tengo es que no me esta sumando la cantidad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, en primer lugar, no es necesario hacer ese `SELECT SUM(...)` dentro del `SELECT` principal, bastaría con restar los respectivos `SUM`.
De todas formas, en estos casos yo siempre recomiendo que antes de hacer el `JOIN`, hayas escrito la agrupación que necesitas para tener más claridad de lo que estás haciendo. Por ejemplo, tu consulta la escribiría así:

```
SELECT SI_Cantidad - ISNULL(T.SI_Existencia,0) AS SI_DIF 
FROM (  SELECT  SI_Num_Articulo, 
                SUM(SI_Cantidad) SI_Cantidad
        FROM SI_Conteo
        GROUP BY SI_Num_Articulo) C
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT  SI_Articulo,
                    SUM(SI_Existencia) SI_Existencia
            FROM SI_Inventario_Teorico_QAD
            GROUP BY SI_Articulo) T 
    ON C.SI_Num_Articulo = T.SI_Articulo 
WHERE C.SI_Num_Articulo= 201925
--AND T.SI_Articulo = 201925 -- no hay necesidad de esta condición, es parte del join
;
```

**ACTUALIZADA**
Ok, voy a ser sincero (y esto lo digo sin ánimo de ofender), pero la consulta que agregaste a tu pregunta es un verdadero desastre. Tiene muchos problemas, incluyendo un `DISTINCT` innecesario, un montón de subconsultas que no están correctas (o que agregan extra carga a la consulta), una mala selección de columnas en el `GROUP BY`, etc. Me da la impresión que la consulta que necesitas se puede escribir de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT  t.SI_Articulo,  
        m.SI_Descripcion,  
        t.SI_UM,
        CASE WHEN c.SI_OV IS NOT NULL THEN '*' ELSE NULL END SI_OV,
        COUNT(DISTINCT t.SI_Ubicacion) SI_Ubicacion,
        SUM(t.SI_Existencia) SI_Existencia,
        SUM(c.SI_Cantidad) SI_Cantidad,
        SUM(c.SI_Cantidad) - SUM(t.SI_Existencia) SI_DIF 
FROM SI_Inventario_Teorico_QAD t 
INNER JOIN SI_Maestro_Ref_QAD m 
    ON m.SI_Num_Articulo = t.SI_Articulo 
LEFT JOIN SI_Conteo c 
    ON c.SI_Num_Articulo = t.SI_Articulo
GROUP BY t.SI_Articulo,  
         m.SI_Descripcion,  
         t.SI_UM,
         CASE WHEN c.SI_OV IS NOT NULL THEN '*' ELSE NULL END;
```

Comment: y como puedo hacer para ponerla en el query que acabe de poner?

Comment: @Eduard ok, actualicé mi respuesta. Para la próxima vez sería mejor que postees de inmediato la consulta en la que tienes problemas para no tener que hacer doble trabajo